# Java: recursive search function

Tags: java

I create an undirected and unweighted graph by `HashMap<Integer,HashSet<Integer>>`. The key of HashMap is the number of the node, and the value of the map is the neighbour of the node.

Then, I want to find all the shortest paths between the nodes. My idea is checking all the neighbours of the source node whether it is the neighbour of destination node or not. If not, it will check the neighbours of the neighbours of the source node.

e.g. 
[image]

I want to check all yellow nodes then check green nodes until finding the neighbours of the destination. But, when I try to use while loop and recursive function to find the shortest path, it will check the first yellow node then check the first green node.

how do I solve it?

Or my idea is fault actually?

This is my code.
The inputData is used to get the data from txt file.

```
static Map<Integer, HashSet<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>();


public static void inputData(Integer k, Integer v) {
        if (graph.containsKey(k)) {
            HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(graph.get(k));
            s.add(v);
            graph.put(k, s);
        }
        else {
            HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();
            s.add(v);
            graph.put(k, s);
        }
        if (graph.containsKey(v)) {
            HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(graph.get(v));
            s.add(k);
            graph.put(v, s);
        }
        else {
            HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();
            s.add(k);
            graph.put(v, s);
        }
    }


public static void findAllShortestPaths() {`

        for (Integer key : graph.keySet()) {
            Iterator it = graph.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Integer k = (Integer) it.next();
                if (k == key) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Integer k = (Integer) it.next();
                if (!(isNeighbour(key, k))) {
                    findShortestPaths(key, k);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static void findShortestPaths(Integer source, Integer dest) {

        HashSet<Integer> sp = new HashSet<Integer>(graph.get(source));
        if (!(isNeighbor(source, dest))) {
            Iterator it = sp.iterator();
            boolean isfound = false;

            while (!isfound) {

                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    if (isNeighbor((Integer) it.next(), dest)) {
                        isfound = true;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: More code, less text. We can't help you if you don't show us what you have done so far.

Comment: What you are describing is Breadth First Search.  It is against StackOverflow policy for us to help you without you showing more of an attempt at doing the work.

Comment: “Talk is cheap. Show me the code.”

― Linus Torvalds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `HashMap` is unordered. So parsing the nodes in a particular order is not possible.

You can use a class to create graph structure. As you are doing something like BFS.

```
class Node {
    List<Node> adjacentNodes;
}
```

You can iterate the list of adjacent nodes. As the list will maintain the order.

Comment: My graph shows the relationship between people, for example, if no.0 and no.1 are friends. Then, they have edges. Is it a BFS?

Comment: You want to parse all yellow before green right ? That is BFS. If you are traversing a node till the leaf then it will become DFS.